# SharePoint 2013 configuration wizard giving invalid sid error?

Tags: 2013, error, installation, configuration-wizard

Well I :

Installed windows server 2008 R2 SP1 on vmware Virtual machine stand alone not in any domain

Installed SP 2013 Pre-requisites
Installed SP 2013 succefully

running the configuration wizard after few steps i get this error

System.ArgumentException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The SDDL string contains an invalid sid or a sid that cannot be translated.

found out that there could be a solution for this on http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointitpropreview/thread/62704a0b-abf6-4b59-a7d5-c68d1e652fc2

but that is now taking to page not found

plz help

Comment: This was very helpful and it worked like a charm. I did have to install the snapin for sharepoint for PS in order to get the New-SPManagedAccount -Credential $SearchService command to work. After that it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you are installing as standalone, service running under Network Service account in workgroup environment is not supported.

check these two blogs and fix the issue.

http://kancharla-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/07/service-running-under-network-service.html
http://kancharla-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/07/the-sddl-string-contains-invalid-sid-or.html

Answer (score 11):

[This forum article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17933.sharepoint-2013-the-sddl-string-contains-an-invalid-sid-or-a-sid-that-cannot-be-translated.aspx) helped me but I have to substitute for the missing "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server" - C:\Program Files\Windows SharePoint Services\15.0\Data\Analytics_{some guid}

> Hi All,
>
> Recently an issue was reported to me where some of my site admins were
>   facing an issue in setting up a SharePoint 2013 stand alone
>   environment. They were facing this error in the step 8 of SharePoint
>   configuration wizard "The SDDL string contains an invalid sid or a sid
>   that cannot be translated".
>
> After spending significant amount of time this issue was finally
>   resolved in this way:
>
> 1. Add the account you want to use for search service in WSS_Admin_WPG group. If you are going to use built in administrator account this
>      should be present by default.
> 2. Then execute this command from sharepoint powershell console: $SearchService = Get-Credential Domain\UserName in our scenario of standalone installation the Domain should be the machine name.
> 3. Then execute this command New-SPManagedAccount -Credential $SearchService
> 4. Now Go to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server" and find the folder that starts with
>      Analytics with a postfix guid.
> 5. Right-click --> Properties-->Sharing-->Advanced Sharing
> 6. Check the "Share this folder' check box and click on Permissions
> 7. Add the Search Service account created in step 2 and select Full Control. Do the same for WSS_ADMIN_WPG
> 8. Run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard again. It should now complete successfully.
>
> Rahul Rashu

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I took 2 days to solve this error... until I found this, thanks for sharing